# How to build Android project with C++ and Curl libraries

Tags: android, c++, curl, android-ndk

I have an Android project (Android Studio, Java based) which was set up using the NDK and native C++ support, as detailed here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code - my sample project with a basic C++ file runs fine.

I've want to use a client's C++ file, which in turn uses the Curl library, like so `#include <curl/curl.h>`

I have also been issued a set of '.so' files, which are libcurl and its dependencies, compiled for Android arm64.

Unfortunately I have very little experience beyond Android and Java, and although I have tried to follow a few guides, I haven't managed to get the project to compile. The `#include <curl/curl.h>` is always highlighted as 'not found'.

Where do I place these .so files in my project, and how do I get the project to build? Many thanks.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#using_prebuilt_libraries

Comment: I think I would need to see a sample project before implementing this myself, cmake is a new world to me.

Comment: i have exactly same problem and i want to add curl to android ndk , if you d find solution , please share it